# Plotting square within square

Tags: python, matplotlib

While plotting square within square, only graph is appearing. I don't know ,whats wrong in my code?

In Pycharm, I am trying to draw it.

'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def square(x,y):
    if (x[1]-x[0]>=1):
       plt.plot(x,y,'ro--')
       x=[x[0]+1,x[1]+1,x[2]-1,x[3]-1,x[0]+1]
       y=[y[0]+1,y[1]-1,y[2]-1,y[3]+1,y[0]+1]
       return square(x,y)
def PlotSquare(size):
    y=[0,size,size,0,0]
    x=[0,0,size,size,0]
    square(x,y)
    plt.title("square")
    plt.axis([min(x)-1,max(x)+1,min(y)-1,max(y)+1])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
def main():
   size=int(input("Enter the size of square:"))
   PlotSquare(size)
main()
```

'''

Comment: The code in the `if` clause is only executed if the second element of `x` is larger then the first by 1. However initially `x = [0,0,...]`, so first and second element are the same. So that code never executes and hence no square will be shown.

Comment: Yes....Now its working...Thanks for finding the error